# Bootstrap navigation bar collapse button size too large

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When I adjust the size of the window to imitate a mobile platform when I click on the toggler, the **Sign In** button becomes **too large**.
Please Have a look at my code here:

https://www.codeply.com/go/QKPKIbiiFo

This are the screenshots of the two different displays:

Mobile: https://gyazo.com/45475835b199968e82ae3410aa2b0b93

Desktop: https://gyazo.com/0a507997dc7ad5edc81a4510a0f6638a

How do I make the button stay the same size?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl fixed-top" style="background-color: black">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Leaderboard</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li, a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues with your HTML.  An `<li>` should not be nested in a `<div>`.  If you address that by instead wrapping list items in a `<ul>`, and then pull the button out of the `<ul>` you should get the behavior you're expecting.  Revised HTML below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl fixed-top" style="background-color: black"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
  aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Leaderboard</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css code:

```
.navbar-nav > button {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

This makes the button take the size to contain its content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stay the same size on mobile as the desktop you can find out what size it's rendering at on the desktop (use the element inspector). It appears to be just under 72px wide

Grab that width that you're happy with and assign that as the width property for the button.

```
.navbar-nav > .btn {
     width:72px;
}
```